# How can I solve this erorr "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libpthreads collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" if i already install pthread library?

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc, libraries, c

**I write this c code and I already install a pthread library writting this command **`sudo apt-get install lpthread-stubs0-dev`

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
 printf("\n%d: Hello World!\n", threadid);
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
 pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
 int rc, t;
 for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++)
 {
 printf("Creating thread %d\n", t);
 rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
 if (rc)
 {
 printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
 exit(-1);
 }
 }
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: What command(s) are you using to compile and link this program? AFAIK programs using POSIX threads should be complied and linked with `-pthread` rather than trying to link the threads library (which is `libpthread` not `libpthreads`) explicitly

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -S pthread.` and `find / -type f -name *pthread*.h` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Execute below commands to get your program (I placed it in *pth.c*) compiled:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential

gcc pth.c -lpthread -o pth
```

And then run it:

```
./pth
```

---

Note: for debugging purposes use `gcc pth.c -lpthread --include-directory=/usr/include -o pth --verbose` and add output of this command to question body.

Comment: thread.c: In function ‘PrintHello’:
thread.c:7:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘void *’ [-Wformat=]
    7 |  printf("\n%d: Hello World!\n", threadid);
      |            ~^                   ~~~~~~~~
      |             |                   |
      |             int                 void *
      |            %p
thread.c: In function ‘main’:
thread.c:17:53: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   17 |  rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);this is the result

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS